# How can I assign labels to features on a RandomForrest model in MLLIB / ApacheSpark

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

I've trained a model using org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest with > 100 features, so the final decision trees look for example like this:

```
> "TreeEnsembleModel classifier with 3 trees
> 
>   Tree 0:
>     If (feature 47 <= 0.0)
>      If (feature 74 <= 0.0)
>       If (feature 62 <= -94069.0)
>        Predict: 0.0
>       Else (feature 62 > -94069.0)
>        Predict: 0.0
>      Else (feature 74 > 0.0)
>       Predict: 0.0
>     Else (feature 47 > 0.0)
>      Predict: 1.0   Tree 1:
>     If (feature 83 <= 0.0)
>      Predict: 0.0
>     Else (feature 83 > 0.0)
>      Predict: 1.0   Tree 2:
>     If (feature 81 <= 0.0)
>      Predict: 0.0
>     Else (feature 81 > 0.0)
>      If (feature 74 <= 0.0)
>       If (feature 52 <= 19.0)
>        Predict: 1.0
>       Else (feature 52 > 19.0)
>        Predict: 0.0
>      Else (feature 74 > 0.0)
>       Predict: 1.0 "
```

This data was read from a CSV file conaining headers which I've saved away before processing:

```
val headerAndRows = rdd.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
val header = headerAndRows.first
```

E.g. I don't want to see "If (feature 47 <= 0.0)" but "If (bloodSugarLevel <= 0.0)"

Any idea how this could be achieved (without me modifying the source code of org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Though i'm not an expert in spark, i checked all the API associated with RF and it seems the only way i can figure out is to match the string with your headers.

For example, replace subString "feature **47**" with header(**47**) using Regex.

Another way is to modify the source code in spark.ml.classification.RandomRorestClassifier